# Regex to allow safe characters

Tags: python, regex

It's my first day with regular expressions. I need help with formulating one. According to the spec, the set of safe characters for anything other than a domain name are as follows: 
`A-Z a-z 0-9 - . _ ~ ( ) ' ! * : @ , ; + ?`

And actually `+` and `?` are only safe when used within a URL, not quite otherwise.

How do I express the set of characters above as a regular expression (i.e. only these characters are allowed, all others excluded).

I had a go at regexr.com. So far I've built `([A-Z,a-z,0-9,+-])\w+.` through trial and error, which is inadequate. Can someone help me with formulating the correct regex here. Btw I use Python 2.7

Comment: what is the pattern that you want to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
r"^[A-Za-z0-9._~()'!*:@,;+?-]*$"
```

This will only match strings that consist of safe characters.

Comment: it also matches empty string, probably shouldn't (easy to fix!)

Comment: That really depends on the use case. The empty string doesn't contain any unsafe characters so it might be the intention to match it. Of course, replace the * with + if that is desired.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid using regex just to test single characters in a string.

I'd use `all` with `str.isalnum` or check against allowed non-alphanums:

```
x and all(x.isalnum() or x in "._~()'!*:@,;+?-" for x in s)
```

- testing if `x` is not empty (empty strings are not valid urls)
- testing `isalnum()` first because there are probably more letters than symbols and thus it would be slightly faster)